# Is overloading the addition operator with an rvalue reference as its left hand operand considered as a good practice?

Tags: c++, c++11, operator-overloading, rvalue-reference

Assuming `str`is a class for storing string values, it would overload the addition operator in order to support string concatenation. Like this:

```
str operator+(const str &a,const str &b);
```

But the problem is if we have something like this:

```
str s=str("Hel") + str("lo ") + str("Wor") + str("ld!");
```

Then it would create 3 temporary objects (as we get a new object in every addition) which aren't really needed in this context.
A simple solution to this problem may be overloading a new addition operator which accepts a rvalue-reference as its left operand and returns this operand also as a rvalue-reference after concatenating it with the right operand. Something like this:

```
str &&operator+(str &&a,const str &b){
   a+=b;
   return std::move(a);
}
```

By having overloaded this operator, then the mentioned statement would just create a single temporary object and following additions will just be concatenated to that temporary object.

My question is, is this method a correct solution for this problem?

Comment: If  you want avoid temporaries, avoid constructing a 'str' in the first place - have operators 'str' + 'const char*', ...

Comment: This is indeed something move operations were designed for. Right on the spot.

Comment: @DieterLücking, you are incorrect. str(s) + "a" + "b" + "c" + "d" will end up with lot's of temproraries created.

Comment: @SergeyA Even without C++11 there should be only one (after =)

Comment: @DieterLücking, of course not. Every + would produce a temporary.

Comment: The simplest thing to concatenate a bunch of strings would be to use some sort of "string builder" (like `std::ostringstream`). Otherwise, the "canonical" thing to do is to overload `operator+=`, and write an `operator+` taking its lhs by value in terms of it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Strings can usually be efficiently moved.

As such, your `operator+` should return `str` not `str&&`.  This means that

```
str const& bob = str1 + str2;
```

doesn't break horribly, or more plausibly:

```
for(char c : str1 + str2)
```

doesn't break horribly.

Second, just take a `str` by value.  If it is an rvalue, it'll get moved in (cheap).  If it is an lvalue, it will be copied (then extended, then returned).  Also cheap.

```
str operator+( str lhs, str const& rhs )
```

finally, you can make the rhs be a template type of anything convertible-to-`str` (or valid-to-add-to-`str`) to remove possibly useless conversions.

In particular

```
str a = str("Hello") + " world";
```

should construct `"Hello"`, then append `" world"` without constructing another `str` object, then move that result into `a`.

You could write a `+` that handles rvalues on both the left and right symmetrically, but that is work, and ironically chained `+` puts the rvalues on the left due to how chained `+` binds its arguments.

Finally, you can go all the way to expression templates, and do (almost) nothing until the result is assigned.  This has dangers, and isn't worth it for something as simple as a toy string class.  If you are writing a serious chain-of-characters class, it might be worthwhile after you had done a bunch of other improvements.

Comment: Although that inhibits RVO. In the case of a cheaply movable type this probably doesn't matter, but it is worth keeping in mind. Also, why optimize for rvalues on the LHS only, and not the RHS?

Comment: @juan lazy (it is more work), plus + associates such that rvalues chain on the left (ironically).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but my problem is, if I even use something like this: str("hello")+" wo"+"r"+"l"+"d" then there would be a temporary object for each '+' in the statement! I want to avoid this.

Comment: @Saturn there would be temporary objects, but their internal state would be torn out and reused regularly, assuming you make them move-efficient.  The `str("hello")` is created, then it is moved, then `+" wo"` is appended, then it is moved, then `"r"` is appended, then it is moved, etc.  Each move is into a new temporary object, but construing a string type via-move (should be) dirt cheap.  Presuming your storage is a `std::vector` or something as reasonable, those moves are a few pointer copies and zeros; no allocation occurs.  And a decent compiler might even be able to elide (not required).